# dynamic button on hyperlink page on click of button

Tags: php, jquery

i am a newbie to jquery..

- this is the question bank page initially...  [initial question
  bank](http://i1375.photobucket.com/albums/ag477/uniqueneeraj/question-bank_zpsa7a0f5f1.png)

  this is the page..[question bank for import](http://i1375.photobucket.com/albums/ag477/uniqueneeraj/edit-test_zps7a49005a.png)
  onclick of "Select From Question Bank"
  question bank page(above mentioned) appears with the new appended button:

HTML for import button(show_test page):

```
 <div class="widget">
 <h4 class="innerAll margin-none border-bottom">ADD QUESTION</h4>   

<a href="show_test.php?ty=questions&test_id=<?php echo $test_id; ?>&test=<?php echo $test;
?>" class="btn btn-primary import">Import from Question Bank</a>
</div>
```

when #import button is clicked..question bank page appears with the appended button
 I want that the button should be appended on question bank page only when import button is clicked on show_test page...
  i dont know how to do this appending between two different pages(i.e button on one page and new append field on another) using jquery and php???

Comment: Please add the image (I can't even load it from that spammy crap image site) and the code you have used here too - and explain which button you are talking about

Comment: i have edit the question..i dont have required reputation to post more than 2 links or images..so sorry for problem.. for code i have just started learning jquery...i want to append button on a different page on click of an option

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. Show some HTML, show some jQuery you have already written and ask SPECIFIC questions. SO is not for "gimme teh codez" type questions

Comment: `<?php if (isset($_GET["test_id"])) { ?><button.... /><? } ?>`